# How to display a listbox or text when a program is running

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

This is my coding. I am facing a problem where it didn't display the ".display_message" while it is still running. I receive the message only after the proc torun {} completed its task. Btw, after 2000 is actually my program running. It is a very long code where I feel it is not applicable so I removed it to simplified it. Please guide me in this. Thanks.

```
proc torun {} {
    set total [.display_pc2 size]
    .display_message insert end "test" 


    for {set x 0} {$x < $total} {incr x} {
        set machine [.display_pc2 get $x]
            .display_message insert end "Copy to $machine now. Please wait..."
            .display_message see end
            after 2000
            .display_message insert end "Copy to $machine done"
            .display_message see end
            after 2000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should completely change the way you write this code and use [idle callbacks](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9926).

The idea is that you create a list of "tasks" to do (probably that would be a list of targets computers), save it somewhere and then process it one item at a time, rescheduling the execution using idle callback.

A sketch follows:

```
proc show_transfer_start {target} {
  .display_progress add ... $target
}

proc show_transfer_result {res} {
  .display_progress add ... $res
}

proc schedule_transfer {target rest} {
  after idle [after 0 [list do_step $target $rest]]
}

proc do_step {target rest} {
  set res [copy --to $target]
  show_transfer_result $res
  if {[llength $rest] > 0} {
    set next [lindex $rest 0]
    show_transfer_start $next
    schedule_tranfer $next [lrange $rest 1 end]
  }
}

set targets [list box1 box2 box3]
set first [lindex $targets 0]
show_transfer_start $first
schedule_transfer $first [lrange $targets 1 end]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done tk (if it's gui what you're doing), but maybe you need some equivalent to `flush` when using `puts` to force-display a message.

Since I can't guess what's done inside the `.display_message` proc.

**Edit:**

Just got an idea: You can use the `after` command to fake-multithread your app.

`after 0 [list .display_message insert end "Copy to $machine now. Please wait..."; .display_message see end]`

Which will run independently from your current proc as event handler. Maybe that fixes your flush problem. (Requires the eventloop or `update` command)

Comment: One should never ever use `update`, see http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255
Especially in library (package) code. The short story is that `update` re-enters the event loop which can lead to perceived re-ordering of events processed by the event-driven code, which obviously sucks.

Comment: The closest concept to an _outgoing_ flush is `update idletasks` (the match isn't exact, but I'd need a fairly long essay to explain why). A flush of _both_ directions is an `update`, and it's hazardous unless you know exactly what you're doing with reentrant code. (I know what I'm doing, which is why I don't use `update` in production code.)